# Why is the code returning a None type object

Tags: python, string, function

`

```
def cal(g):
        if len (g)==1:
            return g
        else:
            s=0
            for i in g:
                s+=int(i)
            cal(str(s))    
a=cal(n*k)
print(a)
```

`

I expected the value of 'g' to be returned but instead i am getting a None type

Comment: Firstly, extract a [mcve] from your code. Then, run that code in a debugger to observe its behaviour. That way, it should be easy to find out what's wrong. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I suppose you forgot a `return` before `cal(str(s))`